# What is another word for "dessert lover"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I just want to know a term for a dessert lover.

Comment: Um...I'm guessing you want something *shorter* to call them. Perhaps this is a single word request? "Shortly" generally is a synonym for "soon" (implying the people are currently being called desert lovers, but some change in terminology is about to happen).

Comment: Do you mean "desert lovers" or "dessert lovers"?

Comment: I mean desserts lovers sorry!!

Comment: @T.E.D. Yes i want a short name to call them..

Comment: [sweet-toothed](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sweet-toothed)

Comment: Are you looking for a word or phrase that is derogatory or neutral?

Comment: For want of a better term, "dessertophile" is used in [foodie blogs](http://www.thepartnerstrust.com/blog/2011/02/10/sweet-rose-creamery-sweet-lady-jane-westside-places-to-cure-that-late-evening-sweet-tooth/) (another [example](http://www.sprinklebakes.com/2012/05/deep-dish-berry-pie-tart.html)).

Comment: @KristinaLopez looking for a single word. like ermanen's sweet-toothed

Comment: One could make an argument for "gourmand".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say they have a **sweet tooth**.  It isn't much shorter but it conveys the idea of people who have a craving for sweets.

> sweet tooth (noun) - a craving or fondness for sweet food  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweet%20tooth)

- "I have a sweet tooth, and if I don't watch it, I'll really get fat.
- "John eats candy all the time. He must have a sweet tooth."

Answer (score 0):

"Dessert lover" *is* the short way to say it. Easier than the more common "He/she has a sweet tooth."  You could say "sweet lover," but you run the risk of being misunderstood.

Comment: You are correct. Sometimes it may be misunderstood. But it is good to hear as sweet-tooth. Thanks

Comment: 'Dessert lover" sounds the sweetest.